Batch Script for batch rename problem with more than 1 removing pattern
I had AI coded for me this batch script to remove pattern "hhd800.com@" from file name within a folder. If duplicate is detected, then the renamed files will have extension "_laplaiX" with X a incremental numbers
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Step 1: Store the filenames in a temporary file list
set /a total=0
del temp_file_list.txt 2>nul
for %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%f >> temp_file_list.txt
    set /a total+=1
)

:: Initialize counter for processed files
set /a processed=0

:: Step 2: Loop through the list of filenames from the temporary file
for /f "delims=" %%f in (temp_file_list.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%f"
    
    :: Increment processed files count
    set /a processed+=1
    
    :: Display the current progress
    echo Processing file: %%f
    echo Progress: !processed!/!total! files done.
    echo.

    :: Step 3: Check if "hhd800.com@" exists in the filename
    echo !filename! | findstr "hhd800.com@" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        :: "hhd800.com@" found, proceed to remove it and rename the file
        set "newname=!filename:hhd800.com@=!"
        
        :: Step 4: Check if the new name already exists in the directory
        if exist "!newname!" (
            :: Extract the base name and extension using the last dot
            for %%a in ("!newname!") do (
                set "basename=%%~na"
                set "extension=%%~xa"
            )
            
            :: Initialize counter and append "_laplai%count%"
            set /a count=1
            :loop
            set "finalname=!basename!_laplai!count!!extension!"
            if exist "!finalname!" (
                set /a count+=1
                goto loop
            )
            ren "%%f" "!finalname!"
            echo Renamed "%%f" to "!finalname!"
        ) else (
            ren "%%f" "!newname!"
            echo Renamed "%%f" to "!newname!"
        )
    ) else (
        echo No renaming needed for "%%f"
    )
    echo.
)

:: Clean up temporary file list
del temp_file_list.txt

:: Keep the window open to view the process
echo Renaming process complete. Press any key to exit.
pause

This code works really well.  But this is only a removing pattern.
However I can't seem to make AI to do the job with remove not just "hhd800.com@" but also other patterns like "~nyap2p.com" and "gg5.co@".
The repeated suggestion that chatGPT made for me is this:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Step 1: Store the filenames in a temporary file list
set /a total=0
del temp_file_list.txt 2>nul
for %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%f >> temp_file_list.txt
    set /a total+=1
)

:: Initialize counter for processed files
set /a processed=0

:: Step 2: Loop through the list of filenames from the temporary file
for /f "delims=" %%f in (temp_file_list.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%f"
    
    :: Increment processed files count
    set /a processed+=1
    
    :: Display the current progress
    echo Processing file: %%f
    echo Progress: !processed!/!total! files done.
    echo.

    :: Step 3: Check if any of the unwanted strings exist in the filename
    echo !filename! | findstr "hhd800.com@ ~nyap2p.com gg5.co@" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        :: Unwanted string found, proceed to remove them and rename the file
        set "newname=!filename:hhd800.com@=!"
        set "newname=!newname:~nyap2p.com=!"
        set "newname=!newname:gg5.co@=!"
        
        :: Step 4: Check if the new name already exists in the directory
        if exist "!newname!" (
            :: Extract the base name and extension using the last dot
            for %%a in ("!newname!") do (
                set "basename=%%~na"
                set "extension=%%~xa"
            )
            
            :: Initialize counter and append "_laplai%count%"
            set /a count=1
            :loop
            set "finalname=!basename!_laplai!count!!extension!"
            if exist "!finalname!" (
                set /a count+=1
                goto loop
            )
            ren "%%f" "!finalname!"
            echo Renamed "%%f" to "!finalname!"
        ) else (
            ren "%%f" "!newname!"
            echo Renamed "%%f" to "!newname!"
        )
    ) else (
        echo No renaming needed for "%%f"
    )
    echo.
)

:: Clean up temporary file list
del temp_file_list.txt

:: Keep the window open to view the process
echo Renaming process complete. Press any key to exit.
pause

And the Output when running the script is:
Processing file: ABC-02~nyap2p.com.txt
Progress: 2/33 files done.

A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
Renamed "ABC-02~nyap2p.com.txt " to "newname:~nyap2p.com="

Why is this the problem? Much appriciated if someone would help
I have 7 files:
ABC-02.txt
ABC-02~nyap2p.com.txt
ABC-04.txt
ABC-04~nyap2p.com.txt
gg5.co@ABC-01.txt
gg5.co@ABC-04.txt
hhd800.com@ABC-04.txt
The result would be:
ABC-01.txt
ABC-02.txt
ABC-02_laplai1.txt
ABC-04.txt
ABC-04_laplai1.txt
ABC-04_laplai2.txt
ABC-04_laplai3.txt
